# what is Jenkins file and how you will write

Tags: testing, jenkins, deployment, build, jenkins-plugins

What is Jenkins file and How we will write?

How to create Jenkins job dynamically using DSL(I'm not aware of DSL)

Answer (score -1):

From 30 page of [Jenkins User Handbook](https://jenkins.io/user-handbook.pdf): `Jenkinsfile is a text file that contains the definition of a Jenkins Pipeline and is checked into source control. In his chapter you can find examples of pipelines.

```groovy
// Declarative //
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            echo 'Building..'
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            echo 'Testing..'
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
             echo 'Deploying....'
        }
     }
}


// Script //
node {
  stage('Build') {
       echo 'Building....'
  }
  stage('Test') {
      echo 'Building....'
  }
  stage('Deploy') {
      echo 'Deploying....'
  }
}
```

Comment: Please can you explain little bit basic things i'm new

Comment: Please clarify  what you mean.